# Polynomial-Why is the answer for removing parentheses and solving different

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am a 45 yo self-taught software engineer and I am finally studying mathematics.  Pretty simple question:

I am using the ALEKS software and during two different lessons on polynomials we get drastically different answers:

When I am supposed to REMOVE PARENTHESES:

$(x+2)(x-2)$  has the correct answer of:

$x^2 + 4x -4$

When I am supposed to SOLVE:

$(x+2)(x-2)$ has the correct answer of

$x^2 -4$

How can both be correct?  Seems very inconsistent to me.

Comment: Only the second one is correct.

Comment: The first one is really strange, are you sure that both have the same question?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "When I am supposed to REMOVE PARENTHESES."  Something is definitely wrong in the first answer.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that when you say "remove parentheses", you are multiplying (x+2) by (x-2), thus simplifying the expression. When you do that you should get: (x+2)*(x-2) = x^2+2x-2x-4 = x^2-4. So the first answer is probably wrong. Also, if you think about it, you can SIMPLIFY these expressions but you cannot SOLVE them: to solve you should have some constraint, like ax^2+bx+c=0. Without '=0' part you CANNOT SOLVE the expression because it is NOT an equation.
If you put this in equation form (x+2)(x-2)=0 then you can see that the solutions are x=2 and x=(-2).